# How to programatically bounce v-dialog

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using [v-dialog](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs/) from vuetify. When I set it to persistent, there is a bounce effect when the user clicks outside the dialog. I would like to manually create that effect when some random button is clicked. How is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dialog has a method called `animateClick`, you can call the same.

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/aaha/pen/povpwrr?editors=1011)

```
<v-dialog ref="dialog" v-model="dialog" width="400px">
  <v-card >
    <v-card-title
       class="headline grey lighten-2"
       primary-title
      >
      Privacy Policy
    </v-card-title>
    <v-card-text>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in 
    </v-card-text>
    <v-divider></v-divider>
    <v-card-action>
      <v-btn @click="doAnimation">Animate Me</v-btn>
    </v-card-action>
  </v-card>
</v-dialog>
....
....
<script>
  export default{
    ...
    methods: {
      methods:{
       doAnimation(){
          this.$refs.dialog.animateClick()
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```